# How to dynamically move to antother fragment screen if first fragment is empty?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 4 fragment activity attached to the main activity in a tab bar.
`frag 1`, `frag 2`, `frag 3`, `frag 4`

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    assert toolbar != null;
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.toplogo);



    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    if (tabLayout != null) {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Videos"));
    }
    if (tabLayout != null) {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Music"));
    }
    if (tabLayout != null) {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("MindMaps"));
    }
    if (tabLayout != null) {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Quiz"));
    }
  /*  if (tabLayout != null) {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Discussion"));
    }*/
    if (tabLayout != null) {
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(parseColor("#ffffff"), parseColor("#f1bf8f"));
    }


    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    if (mViewPager != null) {
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    if (tabLayout != null) {
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Videos();
            case 1:
                return new Music();
            case 2:
                return new MindMaps();


            case 3:
                return new Quiz();

           /* case 4:
                return new Discussion();*/


        }
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 4;
    }
```

Similarly like in the link below.

image [image: link] :

Each contains a listview.
These fragments are getting data from API and shows in a listview.
If the listview is empty in frag 1 how to move dynamically to another fragment which has non-empty list.

Let me know if any clarification needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Answer :   ((FragmentActivity)getActivity()).mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

As I am getting data in JSON format from API

So,on "postexecute" method I checked my List.

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

 if (myList.isEmpty()) {

        moveForward();

    }
  else {
 //do something
  }
    private void moveForward() {


    ((FragmentActivity)getActivity()).mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

//changed my position from 0 to 1
//mViewPager will be package local.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an `interface` in `Fragment` and implement it in the `Activity`. While populating `list view`, if **list size is zero** then trigger this interface. In `Activity` call `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);`

Comment: can u elaborate ur answer @AkshayBhat